# Keras model always predicting 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

so I have data like in the shape of `(10000, 178, 178, 3)` where I have 10000 samples and each have 3 different color channel(not the RGB one), where I have around `8k` samples with label `0` and rest 2k as label `1`. Here's one of my sample data:

```
array([[[[1.79844797e-01, 1.73587397e-01, 1.73587397e-01, ...,
          4.84393053e-02, 5.15680127e-02, 5.46967126e-02],
         [1.76716089e-01, 1.79844797e-01, 1.82973504e-01, ...,
          5.15680127e-02, 5.31323589e-02, 5.15680127e-02],
         [1.81409150e-01, 1.86102197e-01, 1.81409150e-01, ...,
          5.15680127e-02, 5.31323589e-02, 5.15680127e-02]]],


       [[[2.51065755e+00, 2.53197193e+00, 2.53197193e+00, ...,
          1.88543844e+00, 1.89964795e+00, 1.90675282e+00],
         [2.51776242e+00, 2.52486706e+00, 2.53197193e+00, ...,
          1.89964795e+00, 1.90675282e+00, 1.90675282e+00],
         [2.53197193e+00, 2.51776242e+00, 2.52486706e+00, ...,
          1.91385746e+00, 1.90675282e+00, 1.90675282e+00]]],


       [[[7.13270283e+00, 7.11016369e+00, 7.13270283e+00, ...,
          4.85625362e+00, 4.90133190e+00, 4.94641018e+00],
         [7.08762503e+00, 7.08762503e+00, 7.08762503e+00, ...,
          4.92387104e+00, 4.96894932e+00, 4.96894932e+00],
         [7.08762503e+00, 7.08762503e+00, 7.06508589e+00, ...,
          4.99148846e+00, 4.96894932e+00, 4.96894932e+00]]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Now firstly I'm trying to normalize by color channel. As each color channel is completely different so I'm normalizing by color channel as follows, `dara_array` is my whole dataset:

```
def nan(index):
    data_array[:, :, :, index] = (data_array[:, :, :, index] - np.min(data_array[:, :, :, index]))/(np.max(data_array[:, :, :, index]) - np.min(data_array[:, :, : ,index]))
```

Splitting for training and testing:

```
rand_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
train_indices = rand_indices[0:7460]
valid_indices = rand_indices[7460:len(data)]

x_test = data_array[valid_indices, :]
y_test = EDR[[valid_indices]].astype('float')

x_train = data_array[train_indices, :]
y_train = EDR[[train_indices]].astype('float')
```

Then I'm using this Neural Network for training this dataset:

```
weight_decay = 1e-4
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (20,20), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=x_tr.shape[1:]))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (30,30), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

Then here I'm training  it:

```
def lr_schedule(epoch):
    lrate = 0.001
    if epoch > 75:
        lrate = 0.0005
    elif epoch > 100:
        lrate = 0.0003        
    return lrate

batch_size = 128

opt_rms = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = opt_rms, metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size, epochs=10, verbose=1,
                   callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)])
```

Here's the result of my all epoch:

```
Epoch 1/10
59/59 [==============================] - 420s 7s/step - loss: 6.7227 - accuracy: 0.7263 - precision_2: 0.2697 - recall_2: 0.2846 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/10
59/59 [==============================] - 399s 7s/step - loss: 2.7919 - accuracy: 0.7440 - precision_2: 0.3027 - recall_2: 0.2991 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 3/10
59/59 [==============================] - 399s 7s/step - loss: 2.9244 - accuracy: 0.7484 - precision_2: 0.3210 - recall_2: 0.3282 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 4/10
59/59 [==============================] - 399s 7s/step - loss: 3.5013 - accuracy: 0.7509 - precision_2: 0.3246 - recall_2: 0.3261 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 5/10
59/59 [==============================] - 398s 7s/step - loss: 3.1829 - accuracy: 0.7413 - precision_2: 0.3137 - recall_2: 0.3406 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 6/10
59/59 [==============================] - 398s 7s/step - loss: 4.9515 - accuracy: 0.7592 - precision_2: 0.3307 - recall_2: 0.2999 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 7/10
59/59 [==============================] - 398s 7s/step - loss: 2.3082 - accuracy: 0.7613 - precision_2: 0.3539 - recall_2: 0.3588 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 8/10
59/59 [==============================] - 399s 7s/step - loss: 1.8624 - accuracy: 0.7520 - precision_2: 0.3273 - recall_2: 0.3282 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 9/10
59/59 [==============================] - 398s 7s/step - loss: 2.7749 - accuracy: 0.7579 - precision_2: 0.3344 - recall_2: 0.3173 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 10/10
59/59 [==============================] - 399s 7s/step - loss: 2.5800 - accuracy: 0.7513 - precision_2: 0.3288 - recall_2: 0.3362 - lr: 0.0010
```

Now when I'm printing classification report everything is coming `0`:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_bool))
```

Output:

```
    precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.82      1.00      0.90      2030
         1.0       0.00      0.00      0.00       453

    accuracy                           0.82      2483
   macro avg       0.41      0.50      0.45      2483
weighted avg       0.67      0.82      0.74      2483
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing, Am I doing something wrong while normalizing the data or while training or is there something wrong with my model?

Here's one sample image from my data:

[image]

Comment: Try running it for a 100 epochs, with the way you setup the learning rate scheduler it is 0.001 constantly. Or replace it with `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay()` which would be more appropriate.

Comment: @yudhiesh okay I'll try that, thanks for bringing that to my eyes!

Comment: to add on top of @yudhiesh, it seems that your training loss is fluctuating a bit. You may want to experiment different parameter settings e.g. increasing the batch size, lowering initial learning rate, or use a more complex model. But train for more epochs would be my first try too.

Comment: and just as a sanity check, you may look at `y_pred` to see if the minority outputs are decimals between 0 and 0.5, not just zeros.

Comment: @lpounng Okay I'll  try that, actually I haven't tried training for more epoch only because each epoch is taking ```420s``` that also on ```P2XLarge``` instance. But yeah I'll try that now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an argmax on a single output, so it will only ever predict class 0. You can see this is the case by analysing your y_pred variable, or by switching your class labels and seeing that it will continue the trend.

To get around this, use a threshold instead of argmax or change your model to predict 1 output per class. There are ways to optimise this but for an initial test you can use a threshold of 0.5 or so like this:

```
T=0.5
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred_bool = y_pred>=T

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_bool))
```

Comment: okay I'll try that now and it'll take time to train model, so I'll keep you posted. Thanks!